# Why can't I see hats on my phone using the app

Tags: bug, android-app, winter-bash-2015

I am loving the winter bash and I love that there are things to do on your phone to get a hat. But then you can't see them on the phone.
You can't even see a list of earned hats. I am using the android app.

Comment: Are you talking about the app? Or mobile? What phone is it?

Comment: I am talking about the app

Comment: Android or iOS?

Comment: Can't see it on the mobile webpage though either

Comment: I am using android

Comment: Through the iOS app, you can't see it. I think has are displayed using a JavaScript overlay. So you can only see it through a browser with JS enabled.

Comment: @Zizouz212 no. The iOS app is showing hats, though somewhat misplaced. Android app did not get the same attention from the team.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Wait what? Really? I'm not seeing anything in the app...

Comment: @Zizouz212 well, the blog post says we should see. Will try to revive my iPhone to check, this one is just too important to miss... :)

Comment: @Zizouz212 ok I can indeed see hats in the app: http://i.stack.imgur.com/O3q2w.jpg. Maybe you have old version, make sure to take latest from app store.